# Why backward list iteration doesn't display node inserted before head of list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stl

I am struggling with following code:

```
 list<int> numbers;
 numbers.push_back(1);
 numbers.push_back(2);
 numbers.push_back(3);
 numbers.push_front(0);


 list<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin();
 numbers.insert(it, 100); 

 for(list<int>::iterator it=numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++)
 {
    cout << *it << endl;
 }
```

**Output>>100 0 1 2 3**

But when reverse iteration:

```
list<int>::iterator itBack = numbers.end();

for(; itBack != numbers.begin(); itBack--)
{
   cout << *itBack << endl;
}
```

**Output>>5 3 2 1 0**

Where that 5 came from? and why there is no element with number 100?

Thank's in advance

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. You cannot dereference `numbers.end()` what you did at first iteration of loop.

Comment: That's not how you iterate in reverse. You need [reverse_iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator).

Comment: FYI -- This code gives an instant assert() error on the first line of the backwards `for` loop when run in Visual Studio.  The error is "cannot dereference end iterator".  So you are lucky any output showed up.

Comment: I have compiled it using gcc 7.5

Comment: I don't know if gcc has debug options, but Visual Studio automatically will check iterators in debug mode.

Comment: You must use reverse iterators: `for(auto it = numbers.rbegin(); it != numbers.rend(); it++)`. Note: `end` iterator points to the "element" after the last one in the list (it is not valid element). The `rend` iterator points to the "element" before the first one (and it is not a valid element again). All "*end" iterators cannot be dereferenced, because of the reason explained above

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it depends on implementation of STL provided with concrete compiler, not on compiler's options. If code contains assertions, they will trigger in debug mode on GCC too

Comment: For Visual Studio it does rely on compiler options, namely the preprocessor.  By default, when compiling with _DEBUG, the iterator checking is turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have here is that the `end()` is't doesn't return an itterator pointing to the last item in your list, but rather it points to the item *one after* the last item in your list. This allows the following code

```
for(list<int>::iterator it=numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++)
```

to run for every item in your list and only exit when the iterator points *past* the end of your list... therefore printing every element.
For the cast in reverse

```
itBack != numbers.begin()
```

This will become untrue *as* you reach the first element of your list and so won't run for it. Trying to deference `end()`, as mentioned in the comments, has undefined behavior as you are effectively indexing outside your array.